# Galera replication when two nodes can't communicate

Tags: debian, cluster, mariadb, galera

Let's say I have a 3 nodes Galera cluster with MariaDB composed of servers A, B and C. Server A and server B can't communicate between each other but both servers can communicate with Server C. How would the cluster react to this situation ?

From what I tested, it seems that when the connection is lost between A and B, the cluster is still working. I could not however restart the cluster. Is there any documentation on this particular case ? I can't seem to find any.